# with android gesture builder can i save to data directory

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

I have been looking at the gesture builder demo for the android and it works great: provided that you have and SD card.  I'm trying to adjust it so that it will write to the internal storage instead of the SD card.

So far it has been pretty simple,

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
    _sStoreFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), _fileName);
}
else
{
    _sStoreFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), _fileName);
}
```

However, it doesn't want to save any of the gestures that I have created.  I know this is pretty sparse information and I'm willing to post more details based on questions and comments.

Does anyone have suggestions on what to examine to find out why gestures are not being saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these Gesture demo's:

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk